# Sanity & GROQ - How to fetch items that does not have a category?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, sanity, groq

I'm trying to access all the items that does not have `Featured` in their category array. The GROQ code I use is

```
`*[_type == "post"  && *[_type == "category" &&title != "Featured"][0]._id in categories[]._ref] {title, 'mainImage' : mainImage.asset->url, publishedAt, excerpt, slug, categories}[0...6]`
```

But I'm getting 6 posts including ones with `Featured` category. What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I could figure out the solution using Sanity's Vision plugin.

```
`*[_type == "post"&& !(*[_type == "category"&&title=="Featured"][0]._id in categories[]._ref)]{excerpt, "mainImage":mainImage.asset->url, slug}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Sachin Titus while your solution works it's possible to simplify it:

```js
*[_type == "post" && !("Featured" in categories[]->.title)] {
  excerpt, "mainImage":mainImage.asset->url, slug
}
```

in this query, we're looking through all documents only once, while in yours you do it twice (see the `*` which means "all documents") so potentially this should be better optimized and a bit better for reading